Does Gridgain replicate the replication changes it receives from other node in across site replication?
I am planning to use the replication support across clusters using Gridgain in the following way:
I want to set up a GridGain cluster with 3 nodes. I will have 4 such clusters on 4 separate machines. I would like to configure replication among them. So, Site 1 will be replicating to Sites 2, 3, and 4. Similarly, Site 2 will be replicating to Sites 1, 3, and 4. And so on.
First of all, does GridGain support replication in the Mesh topology? If yes, are there any potential problems or known limits? Specifically, when I insert a record in Site 1 that gets replicated to Site 2 and others, does Site 2 also try to send the change (which it received from Site 1) to other sites?

First let's address some terminology. You say you have 4 clusters on 4 separate machines. For me a cluster is more than 1 machine. A cluster is 2 or more machines each hosting 1 GridGain instance and each instance is a part of 1 multi-host cluster. Next let's address replication. GridGain's Data Center Replication is intended to address the challenges of higher network latency that typically exists between data centers. Data Center replication can be established between N number of Data Centers. If you are running 4 single node "clusters" (not a cluster in my mind) and your are running these inside one single data center, then a more optimal deployment strategy would be to use these 4 GridGain instances as one single cluster and then have each participant work on their cache and create the caches as replicated instead of partitioned. If by contrast each of your "clusters" (how many GridGain instances running on one physical host?) are in separate data centers then you can set up DCR between each of your "clusters". Be aware that DCR is established by deploying separate senders & receivers on separate hosts! Also be aware that if you are running multiple GridGain instances on 1 physical host then you do not have protection against host failure. If your host fails then your cluster is down. That is not the case with separate instances running on separate hosts! Hope that helps.

I am hosting 3 Gridgain instances running inside containers on each machine. So this is cluster of multiple Gridgain instance as of now. I can later plan to run the instance in dedicated machine later.
My deployment strategy is fixed, based on requirements.
My question is if I configure each cluster as replication peer then can Gridgain  support that ? For example if A configure cluster 2,3 and 4 as Peer in cluster 1 and do same foe others .

Yes you can do that, but why would you do that? You get no benefits from data distribution that you would get from a multi-node cluster. You get no benefits from data parallelism that you get from a multi-node cluster. You also end up with 4 copies of your data. Do you really need /  want 4 copies of your data?
